# In R: Remove rows/observations based on multiple conditions

Tags: r

Data `x` that I have:

```
x = tibble(
  study = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 
            "A", "B", "C", "D", 
            "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D",
            "A", "B", "C", "D",
            "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"),
  
  method = c(NA, "Gold", "Silver", "Gold", "Silver", NA, 
             NA, "Silver", "Silver", NA,
             NA, "Gold", "Silver", "Gold", "Silver", NA,
             NA, "Gold", "Gold", NA,
             NA, "Bronze", "Silver", "Bronze", "Silver", NA),
  
  number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
             2, 2, 2, 2, 
             3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
             4, 4, 4, 4,
             5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
)
```

My **goal** is to look into each `number` group, if for `method` there are both 'Gold' and another method (whatever it is), then only keep the observations that have 'Gold' and remove the observations that have the other method. When there is no 'Gold' for `method`, then we keep all the observations, i.e. do nothing.

The goal data set should look like this:

```
goal = tibble(
  study = c("A", "B", "C", "D", 
            "A", "B", "C", "D", 
            "A", "B", "C", "D",
            "A", "B", "C", "D",
            "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"),
  
  method = c(NA, "Gold", "Gold", NA, 
             NA, "Silver", "Silver", NA,
             NA, "Gold", "Gold", NA,
             NA, "Gold", "Gold", NA,
             NA, "Bronze", "Silver", "Bronze", "Silver", NA),
  
  number = c(1, 1, 1, 1,  
             2, 2, 2, 2, 
             3, 3, 3, 3, 
             4, 4, 4, 4,
             5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
)
```

You can see that for `number` groups 1 and 3, observations with 'Silver' in the `method` column are removed. For `number` group 5, since there is no 'Gold' at all, we keep all the observations in that group.

The code that I come up with is:

```
test_x = x %>% 
  group_by(number, study) %>% 
  mutate(
    filter_row = ifelse(study %in% c("A", "D"), "keep",
                        ifelse(sum(study == "B") == 1, "keep",
                               ifelse(sum(study == "C") == 1, "keep",
                                      ifelse(method == "Gold", "keep", "drop")))))
```

And unfortunately, it does not work. Any suggestions on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
x_test <- x %>% 
  group_by(number, study) %>% 
  filter(!(method %in% "Silver") | !any(method == "Gold"))

# study method number
# <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#   1 A     NA          1
# 2 B     Gold        1
# 3 C     Gold        1
# 4 D     NA          1
# 5 A     NA          2
# 6 B     Silver      2
# 7 C     Silver      2
```

To test this against your full `goal` dataset, `all.equal(goal, x_test, check.attributes = FALSE)` returned `TRUE`

Comment: Thank you. It worked! Could you explain the code further? First, you grouped by `number` and `study`. Then using `filter` you kept the rows that (1) do not have "Silver" in the method column, OR (2) any other rows that do not have "Gold"?

Comment: Great! The `any(x)` function paired with `group_by()` will return a logical `TRUE` for all observations in a group if *any* observation in the group has a specified value, so by negating it with `!` we are testing to see if no observations in the group have the value. If this worked and no better solutions arise, consider accepting as the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question, why did you use "method %in%" in the first half while use "method ==" in the second half?

Comment: In this case, using `==` or `%in%` yields the same result, but I prefer `%in%` for the way it deals with `NA` values - using `%in%` yields *only* those in the condition, rendering `NA` values `FALSE` where `==` keeps `NA` values as `NA` - try this to see what I mean: `see <- c("Gold","Silver", NA, NA, "Silver", "Gold");
see %in% "Silver";
see == "Silver"`